# currency format in text field through javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to make text field in currency format with 2 decimal place. 
Problem is :- after currency format my value is saved first digit in db instead of full value.

Here is code:-

```
html:-
<?php $itemcost=$item->price;?>
                        <label for="item-price" class="required item-dollar">$</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" 
                                       value="{{number_format($itemcost)}}" id="item-pricing" 
                                       name="price" placeholder="Item Price">
```

Please advise me any solution.

Comment: What type is the database column? You should have this set to something like decimal(10,2)

Comment: I have updated my code. I want my field in currency format with 2 decimal place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear if you are having difficulty saving currency to the database or displaying it

You need to store the value in a field that accepts decimals/floats (e.g. decimal(10,2)

You are also using number_format() without a second argument which defaults to no decimal places, you should use number_format($itemcost, 2) for two decimal places

```
<?php $itemcost=$item->price;?>
<label for="item-price" class="required item-dollar">$</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{number_format($itemcost,2)}}" id="item-pricing" name="price" placeholder="Item Price">
```

http://php.net/number_format